# Faster ways of creating matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following example of something that i've been doing, which is formally simple, but I wanted to check what are the potential alternatives to my code -- in order to get faster, if possible. Here it is the example:

```
Time1=Sys.time()

v=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P"),
         each=1000)

m=matrix(0,ncol=length(v),nrow=length(v))

for (i in 1:length(v)) {
  for (j in 1:length(v)) {
    if (i == j) {
      m[i, j] = 1
    }
  }
}

Time2=Sys.time()

Time2-Time1

# Time difference of 1.405404 mins
```

I am creating a simple relational matrix -- where the vector `v1` could be interpreted as being placed as lines and columns and the matrix maps where the results are equal. If they're equal, we get `m[j,i]=1`; if not equal, `m[j,i]=0`. As I stated, I would like to make this code go faster. I was trying think of a way to code it as an `apply` function, but I haven't figured that out for now. Still, I would like to know if there are other options besides what I've said.

**EDIT**: I made some corrections on the text and I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: FYI, `system.time({...})` will give you the `elapsed` time just as easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this:

Instead of checking for equality of all possible values, we can do it on the vector and replicate the matrix from it to 1000 times by row and by column. It will give the same result. The column and row order is not maintained by this code. But, using the row names and column names, we can verify the answer to be correct or not.

I used `t()`, because column bind is faster than row bind.

```
system.time({
  v1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P")
  m1 <- sapply(v1, function(x) as.integer(v1 == x))
  rownames(m1) <- colnames(m1)
  m1 <- do.call('cbind', mget(rep('m1', 1000)))
  m1 <- t(m1)
  m1 <- do.call('cbind', mget(rep('m1', 1000)))
  m1 <- t(m1)
}) 
# user  system elapsed 
# 9.32    0.50    9.84 


dim(m1)
# [1] 16000 16000
```

---

**Another method:**

This one (hard-coded) will not do any comparison, but we create values based on what can happen by comparing vector with its own values.

It can be improved by using `eval(parse(text=paste()))` construct.

```
system.time({
  m4 <- matrix(data = 
           c(
             c(rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 15000)),
             c(rep(0, 1000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 14000)),
             c(rep(0, 2000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 13000)),
             c(rep(0, 3000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 12000)),
             c(rep(0, 4000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 11000)),
             c(rep(0, 5000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 10000)),
             c(rep(0, 6000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 9000)),
             c(rep(0, 7000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 8000)),
             c(rep(0, 8000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 7000)),
             c(rep(0, 9000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 6000)),
             c(rep(0, 10000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 5000)),
             c(rep(0, 11000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 4000)),
             c(rep(0, 12000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 3000)),
             c(rep(0, 13000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 2000)),
             c(rep(0, 14000), rep(1, 1000), rep(0, 1000)),
             c(rep(0, 15000), rep(1, 1000))), nrow = 16000, ncol = 16000)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.72    0.93    1.82
```

**Note:** 
As @r2evans said, this will not work if the OP's sample data is non-representative of the real data

Comment: `m2` here only has 16 rows

Comment: I much prefer your method of running comparisons *before* replication. I wonder if the OP's sample data is non-representative of the real data, though.

Comment: @r2evans I edited my post. This time `dim()` is taken care of. Please suggest if you find any problem with it. Thanks.

Comment: While the number of 1s is the same, the order of the rows/columns is not the same. Look at `str(m)` and `str(m1)` to see that.

Comment: @r2evans I fixed it with the row names. Thanks

Comment: I never new that `cbind` was (even slightly) faster than `rbind`, interesting!

Comment: I think it happens because R's way of storing data in memory is of column major order.

Comment: That certainly makes sense (now that I think about it that way).

Answer (score 7):

Sure. With the assumption that your sample data is not representative of real data, then this works about 6x faster:

```r
m2 <- +(outer(v, v, `==`))
all.equal(m, m2)
# [1] TRUE
```

If, however, your real data has significant number of duplications, then @Sathish's method of removing duplications before comparison and propagating that through a matrix is likely *much* faster.

Comment: on my machine, the two matrices were created in 96sec (`m`) and 15sec (`m2`).

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans! I believe though that @Sathish's answer works best for what I am working.

Answer (score 4):

I think `outer` approach  by [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61089666/12158757) is the easiest way to construct the matrix. Below is another base R option, using `expand.grid`

```
m2 <- matrix(+do.call("==",expand.grid(v,v)),length(v))
```

Comment: While I didn't think it would be faster than `outer`, I was surprised that it took 53sec (3x as long). I do like `expand.grid` in general, though, nice touch. (I still win by code-golf ;-)

Comment: @r2evans Yes, I agree. I was also writing the `outer` version but found yours has been already there, then I turned to `expand.grid` :). `outer` is more straightforward, since `matrix` in my answer may be the bottleneck

Comment: Would you care to explain a bit more what you did? Why do you need to set the `length` and why the `+` before `do.call`?

Comment: @JohnDoe `+` converts logic values to integers, such that `TRUE` becomes `1` and `FALSE` becomes `0`, and `length` is to define the dimension of matrix

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw my hat in the ring with `CJ` from `data.table`.

```
libary(data.table)
m2 <- matrix(+(CJ(v1 = v,v2 = v,sorted=FALSE)[,ans := v1==v2][,ans]),length(v))
all.equal(m,m2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I had expected something from `data.table` to be a bit more efficient, and I wasn't disappointed. 5.6 elapsed on my machine, not bad!

Comment: Hey, to be fair, the question was not, "what is the fastest way to reproduce this matrix with a single core?"...

Comment: i am just joking.. i was wondering why it was so fast, thats all

Comment: Me too, I am looking forward to the microbenchmark results.

Comment: I posted what I have.. hmmm do you know how the multi-threading works? Does it replicate the matrix?

Comment: Your use of `sparseMatrix` is about 5 times faster than the `CJ` approach on my machine, multithreading or not. Well played sir.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of zeros, then you can use a sparseMatrix. You fill in the positions which are matches, and leaving the rest zeros. This consumes less memory but you can only use it with certain functions. It's used for example in glmnet lasso.

I think @r2evans solution is the most concise and would work for most cases.

Below I have a few codes from the answers, most of them are indeed faster than the OP's

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)
setDTthreads(threads =1)

f_sw = function(v){
N = length(v)
i = lapply(v,function(i)which(v==i))
j = rep(1:N,times=sapply(i,length))
as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i=unlist(i),j=j,dims=list(N,N)))
}

f_r2evans = function(v){
  m2 <- +(outer(v, v, `==`))
  return(m2)
}

f_IanCampbell = function(v){ 
  matrix(+(CJ(v1 = v,v2 = v,sorted=FALSE)[,ans := v1==v2][,ans]),length(v))
}

microbenchmark(f_IanCampbell(v),f_sw(v),f_r2evans(v),times=5)

Unit: seconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
 f_IanCampbell(v) 10.820616 11.325422 12.544146 12.983926 13.126655 14.46411
          f_sw(v)  7.014364  7.228585  8.206858  7.745741  8.877425 10.16818
     f_r2evans(v)  9.117405  9.519443  9.996789  9.896823 10.288586 11.16169
 neval cld
     5   b
     5  a 
     5  a
```